# Uncaught Backbone.localStorage: Environment does not support localStorage.

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am getting this error on chrome. Not sure why its happening. Any help !!
I am using Backbone.localStorage plugin along with Backbone. I am getting error on following line :

localStorage: Backbone.LocalStorage('ideas'),

Error in the console:

**Uncaught Backbone.localStorage: Environment does not support localStorage.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new object from the localStorage class.

```
localStorage : new Backbone.LocalStorage('ideas');
```

The exception is being thrown as Backbone.LocalStorage isn't recognised as a standalone function.

[Backbone.LocalStorage documentation](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage)

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted